# installing a downloaded library from github into vue project instead of just using npm

Tags: google-maps, npm, vue.js

I'm having no luck installing https://github.com/MadimetjaShika/vuetify-google-autocomplete library using npm. I'm new to using vue, and I'd like to install the prerelease developers build, 2.0.0-Alpha.9, as the old one doesn't work with my version of vuetify.

I've downloaded and extracted the zip file and then used npm install (filepath of the downloaded folder), however when i run the project I get a 'can't find module 'vuetify-google-autocomplete' error. I've only installed packages directly via npm before so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to run it because what you downloaded is an npm repo by itself.
Go to the source folder , run the command `npm install` , then `npm run build`, copy the dist folder output to your project. How include that as a module and try.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a specific version of a npm module by using npm tags

```
npm i vuetify-google-autocomplete@2.0.0-Alpha.9
```